# Rails not finding exception notifier plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
$ script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/exception_notification.git

$ ls vendor/plugins/
exception_notification

$ cat vendor/plugins/exception_notification/init.rb 
require "action_mailer"
require "exception_notifier"
require "exception_notifiable"
require "exception_notifier_helper"

$ script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.2)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support \
  /dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant':NameError: \
  uninitialized constant ExceptionNotifier
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support \
  /dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant':NameError: \
  uninitialized constant ApplicationController

>> require "exception_notifier"
MissingSourceFile: no such file to load -- exception_notifier
```

Probably obvious, but I'm tired today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog post has the solution:
[How to Install the Exception Notifier Plugin with Ruby on Rails](http://engtech.wordpress.com/2008/02/06/rails-guide-exception-notifier-plugin/)

The `ExceptionNotifier.exception_recipients = %w(user@domain)` statement in your environment.rb file is probably inside the `Rails::Initializer.run do |config|` block.

If this is the case, placing it after the end of the block will solve the problem.

Comment: I still get the `NameError`. I installed the plugin (not through `script/plugin install exception_notification` because this does not find the plugin but through `script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/exception_notification.git -r "2-3-stable"`) and do the setup in `production.rb` inside `config.after_initialize do ... end`.

Answer (score 2):

For 2.3-stable, you need the following:

Use `ExceptionNotification::Notifier` and not `ExceptionNotifier`.

And don't forget to add  include `ExceptionNotification::Notifiable` in your controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You should install this plugin from specific branch:

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/exception_notification.git -r "2-3-stable"
```

and [configure it exactly as docs are saying](http://github.com/rails/exception_notification/tree/2-3-stable).

or when using Rails Templates (in Your template):

```
plugin 'exception_notifier', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/exception_notification.git', :branch => '2-3-stable'
```

Answer (score 0):

in environment.rb, after the initialize method add:

```
require 'exception_notification'
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it. I get a "no such file to load" error. I thought a plugin merely had to be present and Rails would find it.